# Woo commerce+ Stripe - How to associate one account per currency

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, plugin-recommendation

For woocommerce and stripe experts.

This is a recurring question found online: how to associate one different account per currency using stripe as payment gateway for woocommerce?

The idea is to bypass the conversion rate applied by stripe for international payments.

Example:

Customer pay in GBP -> money goes in account GBP
Customer pay in EUR -> money goes in account EUR

Thanks all!